# Why can't I connect/register SQL Server 2005 on port 1433 TCP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've just installed SQL Server 2005 on a VM on Windows 2008 R2. I cannot seem to register the server in Management Studio.

- The SQL Server service is running.
- The Surface Area Configuration tool shows remote TCP connections are allowed on port 1433 (default)
- Windows Firewall is OFF and the server is on my LAN.
- I CAN register the server on the machine itself.

I can even telnet to 1433 from the remote machine I'm trying to register it from and it accepts the connection, but I still can't register it in SSMS - it says there is a network error trying to connect. What else could be stopping this from working?

EDIT:
I'm wondering if the problem is related to the fact that I've installed it as a named instance instead of the default instance and there are no other instances on the machine?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: SQL Browser Service (sqlbrowser.exe) is running as well?

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong! It's not running. Despite the fact it was set to automatic, I must have forgotten to actually click start! Doh. Now that it's running, it's working fine.

Comment: @Filburt If you repost your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it as that was the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Nick Good to hear it turned out well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server browser service was not actually running. Now that it's running I can connect. Thanks to Filburt for the tip.